# Check a condition between subset of lines of a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I am working with a dataframe and I would like to perform some test on its data. In particular, the dataframe "df" has a lot of points with different properties: its altitude ("Z" column) and a property called area ("A"). In addition, the points are grouped by the "CODE" column.
Here it is a piece of dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [3,12,19,20,21,22,25,26,27,87],
                    'CODE': ['A.10','A.10','A.10','B.365','B.365','B.365','B.525','B.525','A.10','A.10'],
                    'Z': [1410,410,860,436,675,645,1220,1200,886,885],
                    'AREA':[213.501,1555.370,200.286,10.754,1.642,1.648,1.722,1.725,504.990,503.030] 
                    })
```

```
   ID   CODE     Z      AREA
0   3   A.10  1410   213.501
1  12   A.10   410  1555.370
2  19   A.10   860   200.286
3  20  B.365   436    10.754
4  21  B.365   675     1.642
5  22  B.365   645     1.648
6  25  B.525  1220     1.722
7  26  B.525  1200     1.725
8  27   A.10   886   504.990
9  87   A.10   885   503.030
```

Firstly, I would like to group the points according to the CODE which they belong to. Secondly I would like to sort the point according to their altitude (Z property).

```
df2=df.groupby(['CODE']).apply(lambda x: (x.sort_values('Z', ascending=False)))
```

```
         ID   CODE     Z      AREA
CODE                              
A.10  0   3   A.10  1410   213.501
      8  27   A.10   886   504.990
      9  87   A.10   885   503.030
      2  19   A.10   860   200.286
      1  12   A.10   410  1555.370
B.365 4  21  B.365   675     1.642
      5  22  B.365   645     1.648
      3  20  B.365   436    10.754
B.525 6  25  B.525  1220     1.722
      7  26  B.525  1200     1.725
```

At this point, each point should have "Z" smaller and "A" greater than all the points in the previous lines. This is of course true for the "Z" property because I have sorted the points from higtest to smallest, for "A" should be the opposite and the area should increase in each row. However, it is not always true. Consequently, I would like to create another column where to put for each row the IDs of the previous rows where the test is not passed.

```
         ID   CODE     Z      AREA Test
CODE                              
A.10  0   3   A.10  1410   213.501 
      8  27   A.10   886   504.990 
      9  87   A.10   885   503.030 27
      2  19   A.10   860   200.286 27,87
      1  12   A.10   410  1555.370
B.365 4  21  B.365   675     1.642
      5  22  B.365   645     1.648
      3  20  B.365   436    10.754
B.525 6  25  B.525  1220     1.722
      7  26  B.525  1200     1.725
```

I can not understand how to do this last step, probably by a double loop with a *for* cycle (one on the CODE and the other on the Z), but I can't get it. Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show the example of values which should be in this new column?

Comment: "However, it is not always true." <-- give an example of this too

Comment: I edited my question in order to show you the column _Test_ I need. I hope now it's more clear. Thanks.